# A scheme $X$ finite type over $R$, but $\Gamma(X,O_X)$ is not finitely generated $R$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

A scheme $X$ over $R$ is of *finite type* if $X$ is quasi-compact and for all affine subsets $U \subset X$,  $\Gamma(U,O_X)$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

> Is there an example of scheme $X$ finite type over $R$, but $\Gamma(X,O_X)$ is not finitely generated $R$-algebra?

And how does it relates to the Hilbert's fourteenth problem: "$K$ is a subfield of $k(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ does not imply $K\cap k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ finitely generated"?

Comment: I think this has been asked on mathoverflow. Try to google.

Comment: In fact, one can even take a variety. http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nonfg.pdf

Comment: Can we get a counterexample based on counterexamples of Hilbert 14?

Comment: Probably I am just stupid, but $X$ *finite* over $R$ implies that $X$ is affine and $\Gamma(X, O_X)$ is module-finite over $R$, in particular of finite type as $R$-algebra.

Comment: @Cantlog You are right, I am sorry to have missed "type", it is finite type.Thanks,

Comment: See http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr31.pdf, pp 48-49 for an example with $X$ quasi-affine, normal, of dimension $2$.